# Searching for Building Footprints or Building Inventory Data for the Balkans

Tags: footprint

I am searching for free building data and foorprints, preferably GIS shapefiles but data tables are also welcomed, for Albania, Bosnia, and Macedonia. I am working on estimating people per building in a known locations within those countries. Then, applying the values to intrepolate population. Your help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) would be a good place to explore first. Then I would recommend going looking at each countries statistical/data office, and then each city that you are interested.

There are a few other [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=world%20data) on this site about global data which may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Albania

http://tpginc.net/gis/albania/albania.php

Bosnia

http://www.cartographic.com/xq/asp/bosnia/and/herzegovina/gis/data/navmode.r/rid.47/tid.8/sid.0/cid.0/vid.0/oid.0/qx/hub/index.asp

Macedonia

http://www.gisdata.com/Default.aspx?sec=684